# Vuejs Convert Based64 image to image file format issue

Tags: vue.js

I was using Vue Croppa as my image crop library. so every thing was fine i was able to crop image. when there was case of image upload i was stuck since it crop an image in based64 format and when i tried to upload image my file forma didn`t match. so what shall i do to upload and image.

```
<b-modal
      ok-title="Select"
      @ok="generateImage"
      :id="'listOfImage'"
      title="Upload Profile Image"
      class="modal-primary" size="sm">
       <div align="center">
        <croppa v-model="cropImage" id="image"
                :prevent-white-space="true"
                :width="200"
                :height="200"
                :image-border-radius="218">
        </croppa><br />
       </div>
    </b-modal>
```

Below is my javascript code to upload an image to server,

```
  import {axiosWithOutAuth} from '../../../utils/axios-common'
  export default {
  data () {
   return {
      cropImage: {}
    }

  generateImage: function () {
        let Imageurl = this.cropImage.generateDataUrl() // this is default library method to generate image in based 64 format.
        if (!this.cropImage.hasImage()) {
          alert('no image')
          return
        }
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('image', Imageurl)
        formData.append('bus', this.id)
        axiosWithOutAuth({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/buses/gallery/upload/',
          data: formData,
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('user-token'),
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
          }
        }).then(response => {
          alert('sucessfully uploaded')
          this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was..

```
   generateImage: function () {
   if (!this.cropImage.hasImage()) {
     alert('no image')
     return
   }
   this.cropImage.generateBlob((blob) => {
     const formData = new FormData()
     formData.append('image', blob, 'image.jpg')
     formData.append('bus', this.id)

     axiosWithOutAuth({
       method: 'post',
       url: '/buses/gallery/upload/',
       data: formData,
       headers: {
         'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('user-token'),
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
       }
     }).then(response => {
       alert('sucessfully uploaded')
       this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)
     }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error)
     })
   })  
 }
```

We have to pass file name

```
formData.append('image', blob, 'image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `generateBlob` instead of `generateDataUrl`.
You can check out [Upload demo](https://zhanziyang.github.io/vue-croppa/#/demos)

Sample code:

```
generateImage: function () {
   if (!this.cropImage.hasImage()) {
     alert('no image')
     return
   }
   this.cropImage.generateBlob((blob) => {
     const formData = new FormData()
     formData.append('image', blob)
     formData.append('bus', this.id)

     axiosWithOutAuth({
       method: 'post',
       url: '/buses/gallery/upload/',
       data: formData,
       headers: {
         'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('user-token'),
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
       }
     }).then(response => {
       alert('sucessfully uploaded')
       this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)
     }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error)
     })
   })  
 }
```